# Github Actions cloud hosted runner, Container within Container?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am currently working for an enterprise and have been asked to use GitHub Actions instead of ADO/Azure Pipelines or Jenkins.

My objective is to create a self-service model where we have a basic CI/CD framework that teams can use as a starting place for their pipelines.  It has all the security, quality, and governance rolled in, making life easier for devs and reducing duplication of effort. Thus reusable workflows are a must, and being able to launch containers from a build agent/runner/worker is a must.

Let me lay out my understanding of the situation with GitHub Actions:

1. Github Actions can do two things:

   - Launch a Container
   - Run JavaScript
2. Running a container within a container is a considered a bad idea, and in fact, support for it is going away in the near future.
3. GitHub Hosted Runners run in a container.
4. Github Actions don't support Reusable Workflows until Q3 of 2021

If my understanding is correct, then I'm dead in the water:

- A GitHub hosted runner for Actions is basically useless in my case unless I want to write JavaScript.
- It looks like I'm back in the VM business to self-host a runner so that I can use it to host containers instead of running Docker within Docker
- My ability to create a generalized framework for my dev teams is somewhat undermined until GitHub gets around to implementing Reusable Workflows. (I think this is the biggest assumption, most likely to be disproved with a workaround)

Before I push back for a different CI tool, somebody please tell me what I'm missing here or what workarounds make this do-able.

Comment: Where did you find info about `Reusable Workflows until Q3 of 2021`?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, reusable workflows feature here: [link](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/98)
Roadmap with dates here: [link](https://github.com/github/roadmap/projects/1%23card-42486650)
Theoretically Q3 deliverables happen by Sept 30 about 40 days away, but then we have to work the bugs out, so I'm not counting on Reusable Workflows being production ready until some time in Q1 2022.

Comment: Can you elaborate on a couple of things
- By reusable workflows, do you mean templating or having a repo link to some centralize repo that has the workflows to reuse?
- You can run any language you want in a github workflow. e.g go, node, bash. Pretty much it all depends on what packages you install at the beginning of the workflow. 
- You can build/run containers within workflows without issues. I have been using the runs on ubuntu and it works well. If you're talking about issues running container types within a workflow then yes that becomes a bit more complicated in hosted runners.

Comment: @EdwardRomero, Yes, the "Reusable Workflows" feature lets you call an entire workflow as an action. This means you don't have to copy/paste a set of steps that you'll be doing in every pipeline (e.g. scan, build, unit test), you just use the action from your pipeline instance, pass your parameters, and you're in business.
My goal is to create a reusable workflow that does a half dozen operations, many of which expect their own containers.  This would mean containers within containers on a Github hosted runner.

Answer (score 0):

After additional research and some testing, my hypotheses were confirmed:

1. Using a self-hosted runner on a VM is the most straightforward way to solve the "container-in-a-container" problem. It also solves the problem of consuming private/self-hosted package feeds from the runner without whitelisting every i.p. range used by GitHub hosted runners, which something most enterprise InfoSec teams would be reluctant to do.
2. This question had second one rolled in, "How to create a reusable CI/CD framework for an enterprise in GitHub Actions" which was bad form on my part. The most straightforward options are a) wait until Reusable Workflows are fully implemented and worked out b) use a more mature orchestration tool like Jenkins, TeamCity, or Azure DevOps if you can't wait.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at:

1. You might be able to use [create your own GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action#creating-an-action-metadata-file) to share behavior, info on how to call [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses).
2. For self hosted then [`docker-github-actions-runner`](https://github.com/myoung34/docker-github-actions-runner) is a great starting point.